# Simplification Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Does $e^{(-2)\ln x}$ simplify to

1.) $\;x^{-2}$

or

2.)$\;-x^2\;$ 
 ?

If it was (2) it would really help give my my integrating factor, but I don't think that is right. Thanks.

Comment: Sadly, it is 1).  I assume you mean $e^{-2\ln x}$.

Comment: $e^\text{something}$ is positive, and $-(\text{something})^2$ is non-positive, for real somethings.

Comment: @PVAL "tag-removed"? Could you find a better tag?

Answer (score 1):

For $x=1$,

- $e^{-2\ln 1} = 1$
- $1^{-2} = 1$
- $-1^2 = -1$

What do you think?